# Positioning/resolution issues in HTML/CSS, and adding images to pages

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, screen-resolution

So I've finally decided to try and code my own website after doing a basic GFX from my understandings. First off, I'd like to position everything obviously, but for some reason I just CAN'T seem to get the hang of it, it's so frustrating.

The main error I keep getting is that it does not seem like it will fit ANY resolution which irritates me. I've heard to use %, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

The most current error I am running into is that my image does not even show up when I have my code like the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<meta name="keywords" content="Voyage, Voyage Community, Website">
<meta name="description" content="Voyage Community">

<title>The Voyage</title>
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body background="images/Background.png">

<div id="header">
    <div class=".headerImage1">
    </div>
```

This is my css stylesheet:

```
#header
{
width:100%;
height:auto;    
}

.headerImage1 
{
background-image:url('images/Header.png');
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height:120px;
}
```

Any help?

EDIT: This is the latest update:

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("images/Background.png")
}

#header
{
position: absolute;
top: -160;
left: 420;
right: 0px;
}

.headerImage1 
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Now do I do the positioning in HTML instead of CSS?

(Here is an IMG to how it looks currently: http://puu.sh/6Rg11.jpg)
(Just took another SS to show what it looks like on a different resolution: http://puu.sh/6RgHg.jpg - Why is it showing different?

Comment: Open the developer console in your browser (probably F12) and load your page. Look at the network tab. Is your css file loading? Is your image loading?

Comment: Where are your images located? In a folder at the same level as you stylesheet?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle? Do you have a screenshot of what you see? Do you have a drawing of what you want it to be? These would help refine our answers, but mine below addresses three immediate issues without those provided.

Comment: You have `body` inside the `{}` rather than outside it, by the way

Comment: After reading your edits, in my answer, the second part of "the resolution/positioning issue" covers positioning properly.

Comment: Recently updated my post with a new picture.

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding images not showing up:

**First**, remove the dot in `<div class=".headerImage1">`

Classes only have a dot in front of them in CSS style definitions, not in HTML.

The dot itself means, "this is a class" in CSS.

Similarly, if you had `id="words"` in HTML that'd be `#words` in CSS.

---

**Second**, in your CSS use this, and remove `background=` from your HTML:

```
body {
    background: url("images/Background.png")
}
```

---

For both situations, make sure your images actually exist at the URI you are using. If they are off the root directory, start the URI with `/` ( i.e. `/images/` rather than `images/` )

---

### Regarding the resolution/positioning issue:

**First, remove extra spacing.** Make sure to include something like this to remove extra space added automatically, which you don't want if you expect `100%` coverage for anything:

```
#header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* the above remove extra space around and inside #header */
    width:100%;
    height:auto;    
}

/* add this to your body tag in CSS */
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

---

Second, set a location for your `#header` when you use `position: absolute`, like this:

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Incidentally, when you do that second thing, the first is likely not needed, and you don't need to use `width: 100%` either.

---

**Last**, the way you seem to be intending it to work, you want to use an `<img>` tag for `headerImg1` and set your sizing as I showed for `#header` above, instead of sizing the image directly. Otherwise, you need to move your `top`, `left`, `right` attributes to the class as you have it now, rather than `#header` as I did.

Comment: Man you answered quick! Thank you. I had to change the "height" to 100% for it to show up though, when I do auto it will not show up.

Comment: No problem. Does everything seem clear and solve the issues you have so far?

Comment: And I just updated my answer and will check your update.